# get pixel color (screen) from windows service. C#

Tags: c#, service, colors, pixel

I am using this method to get the color of a specific pixel on screen

```
public static Color GetColorAt(int x, int y)    
{
   IntPtr desk = Win32.GetDesktopWindow();
   IntPtr dc = Win32.GetWindowDC(desk);
   int a = (int)Win32.GetPixel(dc, x, y);
   Win32.ReleaseDC(desk, dc);
   return Color.FromArgb(255, (a >> 0) & 0xff, (a >> 8) & 0xff, (a >> 16) & 0xff);
 }
```

It is working correctly from console or windows application, however 
when ran from a windows service it returns an invalid color.

(Win32 class is calling dllImport code from c#)

Comment: Is the account running the Windows Service interactive?

Comment: Sorry, do you have any link or additional information about interactive WS on C#?